# error cannot find module installed from my private repository

Tags: angular, installation, repo

Repository 1 - shared  : I have created one angular 8 application(test-shared) to reuse as shared repository with only module TestSharedModule,

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MultiSelectComponent } from './multi-select/multi-select.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MultiSelectComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [MultiSelectComponent]
})
export class TestSharedModule { }
```

Repostiory 2 - parent application: 
Installed the test-shared application into my parent application by adding the git repository details in 
package.json.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "test-shared": "git+https://XXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@bitbucket.org/XXXXXXX/test-shared.git",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
```

node modules installed successfully , but when i'm trying to import shared module to parent module throwing error "cannot find module 'test-shared'"

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
**import {TestSharedModule} from 'test-shared'**


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule   , 
    TestSharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

can someone please check what wrong i did ?

[image]

Comment: when you import 'test-module' webpack searches "main" file from package.json field, and in your case it seems there is no main file here. try creating one and export TestsharedModule from it.

Comment: Could you please explain bit more ?